# how to update node version form 12 to 16 in debian?

Tags: node.js

My current version is 12.22.12. How to update to version 16?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm):

```bash
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash
```

After installation:

```bash
nvm install 16
```

And finally, use your desired version:

```bash
nvm use 16
```

Confirm version:

```bash
node -v
```

Comment: I am getting this below error message
"Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com" 
Please tell me another way

Comment: Try pinging google.com, seems like you don't have internet connection: `ping google.com`

Comment: thanks a lot. its working fine as expected. Kudos...